# do I need to add wait time to get restful service response for safety?

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, rest, httpclient

I am using httpclient to hit rest service. I am getting json data  from rest service and I am doing further processing on it. But what if due to some reason, I couldn't get response quickly and main thread continue its execution without waiting for response?

Do I need to handle this case?

I am calling rest service as

```
            DefaultHttpClient client=new CustomHttpClient();
            HttpGet reqG;
            HttpResponse respG=null;
            HttpEntity entity;
            reqG= new HttpGet(url);
            respG= client.execute(reqG);
            entity = respG.getEntity();
            InputStream is=entity.getContent();
```

Do  I need add Thread.sleep() after client.execute(reqG) OR
is there  any better way to do it?

Please advise.

Comment: Why would you sleep the thread?  If this operation is asynchronous then it should have some mechanism for calling back to consuming code, shouldn't it?

Comment: Don't you have something like `onPostExecute`?

Comment: No i don't have onPostExecute, I am using simple java with httpClient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q. main thread continue its execution without waiting for response?
>
> A. **No, the main thread will not continue its execution until some response
>   comes**.

If your service takes too much time, then there may be a request timeout.